Permutation Feature Importance in the Context of Cross Validation
I am considering two apporaches to calculate the mean, std and standard error (se) for permutation feature importance during cross-validation splits.
Approach 1: Calculate the mean, standard deviation (std), and standard error (se) for all scores across all CV splits and shuffles:
Given:

$X_{i,j,k}$ = importance score of feature $i$ from shuffle $j$ of CV split $k$.
$N$ = number of CV splits
$M$ = number of shuffles per split $\forall$ $i, k$

First, calculate the importance score for each feature using all scores coming from each shuffle and each CV split:
$Mean_i = (\sum_{k=1}^{N} {\sum_{j=1}^{M} {X_{i,j,k}}}) / (M*N)$
then calculate the standard deviation (std) and standard error (se):
$Std_i = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{N} {\sum_{j=1}^{M} ({{X_{i,j,k}} - Mean_i)^2}} / (M*N) - 1)}$
$Se_i = Std_i / \sqrt{(M*N)}$
Approach 2: Calculate the mean, std, and se for summed scores across each CV split and shuffle:
First, calculate the summed importance score (or average importance score) for each feature in each CV split:
$Y_{i,k} = \sum_{j=1}^{M} X_{i,j,k}$
$Mean_{i} = (\sum_{k=1}^{N} Y_{i,k}) / N$
Then calculate the standard deviation and standard error:
$Std_i = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{N} {(Y_{i, k} - Mean_i)^2} / (N - 1)}$
$Se_i = Std_i / \sqrt{N}$
This $Std_i$ and $Se_i$ capture the variability of the feature importance between different CV splits but do not fully capture the variability across individual shuffles within each CV split.
What would be diffference in the interpretation of feature importance mean, std and se from these two apporaches?
